# Why does mutably borrowing fix an expected trait implementation?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I am using rust sqlx and I am getting a connection from my DB pool for my query:

```
POOL: OnceCell<Pool<Postgres>> = OnceCell::new();

pub async fn get_connection() -> PoolConnection<Postgres> {
    POOL.get().unwrap().acquire().await.unwrap()
}

pub async fn fetch_users() -> Result<Vec<User>> {
    let result = sqlx::query_as!(User,
        r#"SELECT * FROM users"#)
        .fetch_all(get_connection().await).await?;
        Ok(result)
}
```

But `get_connection().await` is giving me an error:

> `` the trait bound `sqlx::pool::PoolConnection<sqlx::Postgres>: sqlx::Executor<'_>` is not satisfied expected an implementor of trait `sqlx::Executor<'_>` ``

The compiler is telling me to fix by `` using consider mutably borrowing here: `&mut` ``  which works fine when I change to `&mut get_connection().await`.

I don't understand why this fixes the issue. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [implementations](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/trait.Executor.html#implementors) for `sqlx::Executor`, all of them are on some `&mut T` type. It is implemented for `&mut PoolConnection<Postgres>` but not `PoolConnection<Postgres>`.

Adding `&mut` changes it from passing a `PoolConnection<Postgres>` into a `&mut PoolConnection<Postgres>`. This is required since Rust does not auto-borrow function parameters.

Comment: Ok, so its just how sqlx has implemented Executor.